# Firefox extension to let the user open YouTube videos with SMPlayer or VLC conveniently?

Tags: firefox, media-player, youtube

VLC and SMPlayer have the ability to stream YouTube videos.

Is there an extension for Firefox to conveniently open the video in the current YouTube page in SMPlayer or VLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is more than one:

- [vlc context menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/vlc-context-menu/) lets you right click on any music or video urls to add them to your vlc play list.
- [VLC YouTube Shortcut](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/vlc-youtube-shortcut/?src=search) specific to YouTube both lets you enqueue and open.