# YouTube viewing app for Android that allows skipping forward/backwards

Tags: android, video, youtube

Is there a YouTube video viewing app for Android that allows the user to skip forward or backwards about 10 seconds in the video?

When I am watching a video, sometimes I don't quite understand something, and want to go back 10 seconds.  The only way I can currently do that is by trying to hit exactly the right spot on the progress bar.  But for long videos, that is an exercise in futility.

I prefer a gratis app, but a paid app is fine.

Answer (score 1):

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) would fit the bill nicely:

- Free (Gratis & Open Source)
- Cross Platform
- can play streams, including YouTube videos
- Displays the current time
- Jump to a specific time with Ctrl-T
  [image: Goto Time]
- Ctrl-T is automatically populated with the current time
- You can select the Hours, Mins or Secs field and then use the Up/Down control or just type.
- Also custom bookmarks are available, (for bits you need to go back to).
- Depending on your browser there are plugins for most you can install a plug in that allows you to open VLC as your viewer of the video on a given page or to add the video from the current page to the playlist, e.g. see [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35115/firefox-extension-to-let-the-user-open-youtube-videos-with-smplayer-or-vlc-conve) question for Firefox plugin.